# cy.intercept when GET is being called multiple times

Tags: get, mocking, cypress, fixtures

I am trying to mock out with using fixtures. However, how the code is working is that it is going through a list of IDs and making multiple GET requests. If I have multiple data being displayed from all of the GET request, how can I mock it out? Right now I think it is just showing the previous intercept's fixture...

```
cy.intercept("GET", "/api/item/*", {
fixture: "test.json", });

cy.intercept("GET", "/api/item/*", {
fixture: "test2.json", });
```